# Trying to Create a Basic Array Utility in C

Tags: c, arrays, header, boolean, malloc

I haven't worked with C in ages and as such I've forgotten an embarrassing amount about how C works. I am trying to create a header, 'arrayUtils.h' and a corresponding 'arrayUtils.c' where I define the prototyped functions. Then I am trying to call one of these functions in a second .c file

Header Contents:

```
#define _OUT_OF_RANGE_ = NAN

#ifndef INT_ALLOCATE_H
#define INT_ALLOCATE_H
int * allocIntArray(const int size);
#endif

#ifndef INT_ACCESS_H
#define INT_ACCESS_H
int accessIntArray(const int index, const int * array, const bool checked);
#endif

#ifndef INT_FREE_H
#define INT_FREE_H
int freeIntArray(int * array);
#endif
```

Source for header:

```
/* Allocates an array of integers equal to length size
 * Args: int size: length of the array
 * Return: Allocated array
 */
int * allocIntArray(const int size){
    /*Assert that size of array is greater than zero*/
    if(size <= 0){
        return(-1);
    }
    else{
        return((int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int)));
    }
}
/* Returns the value of the array 
 * Args: int    index:   position in the array to access
 *       int  * array:   array to access
 *       bool   checked: if the access should be checked or not
 * Returns: integer at position index
 */
int accessIntArray(const int index, const int * array, const bool checked){
    /*unchecked access*/
    if(!checked){
        return(array[index]);
    }
    /*checked access*/
    else{
        if(index <= 0){
            return(_OUT_OF_RANGE_)
        }
        double size = (double)sizeof(array)/(double)sizeof(int)
        if(index => (int)size){
            return(_OUT_OF_RANGE_)
        }
        else{
            return(array[index])
        }
    }
}

/* Frees the allocated array 
 * Args: int * array: the array to free
 * Returns: 0 on successful completion
 */
int freeIntArray(int * array){
    free(array);
    return(0);
}
```

Then calling in a second source file:

```
#include "arrayUtil.h"
int main(){
    int * array = allocIntArray(20);
    return(0);
}
```

When I compile with:

```
gcc utilTest.c
```

I get this error:

> arrayUtils.h:10: error: syntax error before "checked"

Initially I was using "bool checked" in accessIntArray, and got the same error but with bool instead of checked.

Sorry if this isn't a specific question but I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: `const bool` sounds redundant, since the `bool` is not a pointer, and therefore it doesn't matter if you change it or don't change it, since you're sending a copy anyway. The same thing is true for the `const int` the function is taking.

Comment: Joe, I tried copying the exact piece of header contents that you attached and tried compiling it using `g++` . I could not reproduce this issue. I am not sure of `gcc` , I dont think it will throw an error in `gcc` either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bool` is not a standard type in C.  The C99 language standard added the new type `_Bool` for a boolean data type, as well as the header file `<stdbool.h>` which defines `bool`, `true`, and `false` to map to `_Bool`, `(_Bool)1`, and `(_Bool)0` respectively.

If you're compiling using a C99 compiler, just be sure to `#include <stdbool.h>` before using the `bool` keyword.  If not, define them yourselves, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned char bool;  // or 'int', whichever you prefer
#define true ((bool)1)
#define false ((bool)0)
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really silly. I'm assuming GCC is C99, but I'll stick with integers for now. There is a new issue of "undefined reference to `allocIntArray'" I was hoping GCC would compile and link automatically, I guess I need to refresh on makefiles.

Comment: @Joe, GCC can compile both C99 and C89 code (and has partial support for C11). To specify that your code is C99, you need to add `-std=c99` to the `gcc` command. Take a look at the GCC pages on [standards](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) and [dialects](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) for more about this.

Comment: In order to compile and link you have to use `gcc arrayUtils.c utilTest.c -o utilTest`

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have a 'bool', you probably just want to use an int. Or C++, which does have boolean types.

Comment: C99 defines `bool` in `stdbool.h`.